# .BAT - Splitting %string% into filename + filepath + file's folder + file's parent folder

Tags: string, batch-file, split

I'm creating a .bat file that is creating customised tv recording icons for mediaportal tvserver and need your help. I start with the following string

```
SET "path_and_filename=D:\TEMP FOLDER\TV RECORDINGS\TV3\Campbell Live\Campbell Live - 2012-10-25 - S38536.ts"
```

I'm trying to create 4 seperate variables from %path_and_filename% containing

1. The filename (without extension)
   eg. Campbell Live - 2012-10-25 - S38536
2. The filepath
   eg. D:\TEMP FOLDER\TV RECORDINGS\TV3\Campbell Live\
3. The file's parent folder
   eg. Campbell Live
4. The file's parent parent folder
   eg. TV3

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily done using FOR variable modifiers and `.` for current folder and `..` for parent folder. (type `HELP FOR` from command prompt to get info on modifiers at bottom of help)

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET "path_and_filename=D:\TEMP FOLDER\TV RECORDINGS\TV3\Campbell Live\Campbell Live - 2012-10-25 - S38536.ts"
for %%F in ("%path_and_filename%") do (
  set "fileName=%%~nF"
  set "filePath=%%~dpF"
)
for %%F in ("%filePath%.") do set "fileParentFolder=%%~nF"
for %%F in ("%filePath%..") do set "fileGrandparentFolder=%%~nF"
set file
```

Sample output:

```
fileGrandparentFolder=TV3
fileName=Campbell Live - 2012-10-25 - S38536
fileParentFolder=Campbell Live
filePath=D:\TEMP FOLDER\TV RECORDINGS\TV3\Campbell Live\
```